# Query for the value of a field matched only if a specific set of rows exist

Tags: mysql, sql, select

That is, let's say I have a table of people and the items they carry -- let's call the columns `id`, `personid`, and `itemid`.  I want to find only the people who carry all of a given set of items; that is, the `personid`s of those with rows having `itemid`s of a given set of values.

What's a good way I might do this?

Comment: Please stop writing tags in titles.

Comment: The relational operator you require is [division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) ("the supplier who supplies all parts").

Comment: Yes that's what I was looking for.  Thanks for giving me something to call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give this proper closure, here's onedaywhen's answer comment as a regular 'answer':

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT personid, item FROM items WHERE itemid IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Change `(1, 2, 3)` to your `itemid`s separated by commas.

If you only care about the `personid`, i.e. not the item they have, then the following might serve you better:

```
SELECT DISTINCT personid FROM items WHERE itemid IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Doesn't this return the people who have ANY of the given listen items (but not all)?

Comment: Is there a good way to get those with all of the specified items?